# How do I make 2D array data members in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, member

What I have now are data members, each with a varying number of arrays with a length of 4:

```
const obj={
    member1:{
        a1:[1,2,3,-4],
        a2:[0,1,-8,-1],
        a3:[-.10,9,5,110]
    }
    member2:{
        a1:[1,0,8,-4],
        a2:[-11,1,-8,-67],
        a3:[-.10,2,5,110]
        a4:[108,15,16, 17]
    }
    //...and so on
}
```

But I would prefer each data member to have a 2D array of various sizes, something like:

```
const obj={
   member1:{
      //2D array of a unique size
   }
   member2:{
      //2D array of another unique size
   }
   //...and so on
}
```

Comment: what means `1x by 4`? which data do you want for that?

Comment: newArray:[[1,2,3,-4],
        [0,1,-8,-1],
        [-.10,9,5,110]]

Comment: @Nina Scholz "Each with a varying number of arrays with a length of 4"

Comment: @Mot : your question is not clear.  I recommend that you update your question and show us the data structure you want, with the data you're showing in the first example, so we can understand what it is you're after.

Comment: @devlin carnate I'm asking how to make 2D array data members.  Because I don't know how to do that, I am unable to fill in the data in the second example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are looking to make a 2D array, you can simply build them like this :

```
const obj={
    member1:{
        a : [
            [1,2,3,-4],
            [0,1,-8,-1],
            [-.10,9,5,110]
        ]
    }
    member2:{
        a : [
            [1,0,8,-4],
            [-11,1,-8,-67],
            [-.10,2,5,110]
            [108,15,16, 17]
        ]
    }
    //...and so on
}
```

And access them as you usually do :

```
obj.member1.a[0][1] // for instance
```

Comment: This answers my question, thank you.  Alas, I can't vote it back up.

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) for nested arrays.

```js
var object = { member1: { a1: [1, 2, 3, -4], a2: [0, 1, -8, -1], a3: [-.10, 9, 5, 110] }, member2: { a1: [1, 0, 8, -4], a2: [-11, 1, -8, -67], a3: [-.10, 2, 5, 110], a4: [108, 15, 16, 17] } };
 
Object
    .keys(object)
    .forEach(k => object[k] = Object.values(object[k]));
    
console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

If I'm reading this correctly I think you are looking for

```
const obj = {
  member1: [
    [1,2,3,-4],
    [0,1,-8,-1],
    [-.10,9,5,110]
  ],
  member2: [
    [1,0,8,-4],
    [-11,1,-8,-67],
    [108,15,16,17]
  ]
};
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  How do you convert the OP's data structure to this data structure you've shown?

Comment: This is helpful, but unfortunately I can't vote it back up.